# Data Validation: Checking Real Data Based on Benchmark Data

Tags: r, validation, dataframe

I have a data set containing variables such as name, nationality, and sex. I want to **check the correctness of the sex variable** of this data set based on a benchmark data set that contains correct sex-values for each name-nationality-combination.

Consider the two example data sets below:

```
# Real data set that should be validated
df_real <- data.frame(name = c("Kevin", "Marie", "Rute", NA, "Charles", "Bruno"),
                      nationality = c("USA", "DE", "PT", "FR", NA, "PT"),
                      sex = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, NA)) # 1 = Male; 2 = Female

# Correct data set as basement for validation
df_check <- data.frame(name = c("Alfons", "Kevin", "Kevin", "Kevin", "Rute", "Charles", "Bruno", "Anne"),
                       nationality = c("FR", "USA", "DE", "PT", "PT", "FR", "PT", "LU"),
                       sex = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2))
```

The column sex of `df_real` should be checked for correctness based on `df_check`. In the example, all sex values would be correct beside the third row (i.e. Rute should be a female in `df_real`).

There need to be considered several additional data conditions:

- `df_real` has several NAs. If any value of a row in `df_real` is NA, the check of this row should be skipped.
- Names that occur in `df_real` do not always occur in `df_check`. In this case, the check of this row should be skipped as well.

**The final output should be a dummy vector with length of `nrow(df_real)` containing 0 (i.e value is correct or the check was skipped) and 1 (i.e. value is incorrect).**

Expected output:

```
output_check <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

I tried to solve this with complicated for-loops and if-conditions. However, since my data is very large this takes a lot of computation time. I am sure there must be an easier solution based on `apply()` functions which I unfortunately cannot figure out.

Comment: Do you need `library(data.table);setDT(df_real)[df_check, flag := 1, on = names(df_real)];df_real[is.na(flag), flag := 0]`

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your comment. If I run your code I receive the flag `c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`, but it should be `c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `left_join` both the tables on `name` and `nationality` then check both the `sex` columns and assign value 1 in case they are different values and `replace` the non-matching `NA`s with 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_real %>% 
  left_join(df_check, by = c("name" = "name","nationality" = "nationality")) %>%
  mutate(check = +(sex.x != sex.y)) %>%
  replace_na(list(check = 0)) #%>%
  #select(-sex.x, -sex.y) #if you don't need sex columns


#     name nationality sex.x sex.y check
#1   Kevin         USA     1     1     0
#2   Marie          DE     2    NA     0
#3    Rute          PT     1     2     1
#4    <NA>          FR     2    NA     0
#5 Charles        <NA>     2    NA     0
#6   Bruno          PT    NA     1     0
```

---

Using same logic with base R `merge`

```
df1 <- merge(df_real, df_check, by = c("name", "nationality"), all.x = TRUE)
df1$check <- +(df1$sex.x != df1$sex.y)
df1$check[is.na(df1$check)] <- 0

df1
#     name nationality sex.x sex.y check
#1   Bruno          PT    NA     1     0
#2 Charles        <NA>     2    NA     0
#3   Kevin         USA     1     1     0
#4   Marie          DE     2    NA     0
#5    Rute          PT     1     2     1
#6    <NA>          FR     2    NA     0
```

The order in which output is displayed differs in base R.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use the tydiverse solution, but both solutions do exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `data.table` to do a join on 'name', 'nationality' to create the 'check' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_real)[df_check, check :=  +(sex !=  i.sex), on = .(name, nationality)]
df_real[is.na(check), check := 0]
df_real
#      name nationality sex check
#1:   Kevin         USA   1     0
#2:   Marie          DE   2     0 
#3:    Rute          PT   1     1
#4:    <NA>          FR   2     0
#5: Charles        <NA>   2     0
#6:   Bruno          PT  NA     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JSP No problem.  I assume that you don't need any `sex.x` or `sex.y` columns in your original data